# REST Service - call from ASP.NET 4.0 fails for certain passwords

Tags: rest, webforms, passwords, asp.net-4.0

I am calling a REST based service API from a ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms application.

The REST service requires HTTP Basic Auth and this has worked just fine so far. I'm using this code snippet to define my credentials for my `HttpWebRequest` object (`serviceUsername`, `serviceUserPassword` and `serviceUrl` are strings being passed in):

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(serviceUsername, serviceUserPassword);

HttpWebRequest httpReq = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
httpReq.Credentials = credentials;
httpReq.Method = "GET";
httpReq.Accept = "application/json";
```

and then I fire off my request.

Today, suddenly, for one customer, things went haywire. Nothing seemed to work anymore - all my calls were rejected with a `HTTP 401 - Unauthorized` - even though, using the same URL and credentials, I was able to call this REST API from Fiddler.

The ultimate reason was a `£` character in the password......

So Fiddler seems to have handled that gracefully, somehow - while ASP.NET falls flat on its nose. What extra step do I need to do in order for ASP.NET 4.0 to **also** work gracefully even if my customer decides to put a pound symbol in their (probably machine-generated) password? Any tricks or way to handle this?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I have IIS setup to serve a static .json file, which I added Basic authentication to (which I confirmed by trying to access via the browser). Entering the username / password gives me access (and I get a 401.1 when I don't) - just to confirm that the file really is protected. Using your code, I was able to access the file when the password ended in a pound character. This was the code I used: https://gist.github.com/vcsjones/4122da60576af406bedb

Comment: did you figure out the problem in the end?

Comment: @dmportella: unfortunately - no. I just stopped using special characters like `£` in my passwords....

Comment: its a shame would-be good to get answer for this in the site. must have been something to do the environment.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the encoding type? That character doesn't seem to be normal ASCII